Colorbar to illustrate the change of a specific parameter
I have plotted a sine function where the period is varied. I have included my code below.
tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];
Plot[tab , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True]


To help identify which curve corresponds to which value of a, I thought to create a colorbar that runs from 1 to 2 (the color of the curves would need to change). Is this possible using Plot? This is the best way that I can think of to help identify each curve, especially if the number of curves is increased.

related q/a: Plot many curves on the same graph

Clear["Global`*"];
tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];

Plot[tab, {x, 0, 2 π}
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {1, 2}]] & /@ 
    Range[1, 2, 0.25])
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1, 2}}], After]
 ]




Addendum:
To include Tooltips:
Clear["Global`*"];
tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];
labels = "a=" <> ToString@NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] & /@ Range[1, 2, 0.25];
items = Transpose[{tab, labels}]
Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[First@#, Last@#] & /@ items], {x, 0, 2 π}
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {1, 2}]] & /@ 
    Range[1, 2, 0.25])
 , PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1, 2}}, LegendLabel -> "a"], After
   ]
 ]


Maybe this is what you're looking for?
tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];
Plot[tab, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


Edit:
  Plot[tab, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 
   "a=" <> ToString@NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] & /@ Range[1, 2, 0.25], 
   LegendLabel -> "sin(ax)"]]



tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];

Using PlotLabels and Tooltip
Plot[Tooltip @ tab, {x, 0, 2.1 Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], None}},
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic},
 PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]



$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

tab = Table[Sin[a  x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];

To facilitate visually identifying an individual curve, use Manipulate
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@Tooltip[tab], {x, 0, 2  \[Pi]},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> ({ColorData["Rainbow"][# - 1], Thickness[If[hl == #,
         0.009, 0.005]]} & /@
     Range[1, 2, 0.25]),
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1, 2}}]],
 {{hl, None, "highlight"}, Prepend[Range[1, 2, 0.25], None],
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]



Another method to "help identify which curve corresponds to which
value of a" is to use one of the many PlotHighlighting options:
Mousing over or pointing at one of the curves highlights the plot at
the given position.
PlotHighlighting was introduced in V 13.1
tab = Table[Sin[a x], {a, 1, 2, 0.25}];

Plot[Evaluate @ tab, {x, 0, 2.1 Pi},
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], None}},
 PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline",
 PlotLabels -> "Expressions",
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.004]]


